# How to stop loading an image in Glide if it takes a long time to load?

Tags: android, time, android-glide, image-loading

It is critical for me that the picture is loaded for a certain time, if during this time it cannot be loaded, then I want to stop loading and move on to the next function.

It seems that here it is necessary to somehow throw an exception, but an important condition is the time for loading the picture, which I can regulate myself.

I think this logic should be here

```
onLoadFailed
```

but maybe here

```
onResourceReady
```

Let me please know if anyone has come across this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a timeout as described in the [documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html#component-options):

```
Glide.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .option(MyCustomModelLoader.TIMEOUT_MS, 1000L)
  .into(imageView);
```

Comment: thanks, this puts me on the right track, but I couldn't find an example implementation of `MyCustomModelLoader` anywhere. Can you suggest what it looks like?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an implementation of a model loader at hand, but you can see the example of creating one: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/tut/custom-modelloader.html

Comment: you can also simply use `.timeout(1000L)` after `load()`